# Is there a way to configure the URL used by GooglePublicKeysManager in firebase-admin java SDK?

Tags: firebase, kotlin, proxy, firebase-admin

I have a Kotlin application behind corporate proxy and the company provided me a proxed URL to connect to https://www.googleapis.com.

I have replaced such URL in my serviceAccountCredentials.json file, which is used to initialize FirebaseApp. So I have something like this:

```
{
  ...,
  "auth_provider_x509_cert_url": "https://<PROXED_URL>/oauth2/v1/certs",
  "client_x509_cert_url": "https://<PROXED_URL>/robot/v1/metadata/x509/...",
  "universe_domain": "<PROXED_URL>"
}
```

Here is the function that initialize Firebase:

```
private fun initializeFirebase(@Observes startupEvent: StartupEvent) {
        try {
            val serviceAccount = this::class.java.getResourceAsStream(credentialsPath)
            val options = FirebaseOptions.builder()
                .setCredentials(GoogleCredentials.fromStream(serviceAccount))
                .build()
            FirebaseApp.initializeApp(options)
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            LOG.error("Failed to initialize Firebase: ${e.message}")
            LOG.error(e.stackTraceToString())
        }
    }
```

However, when I try to verify a token using firebase, I get the following error:

```
com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuthException: Error while fetching public key certificates: connect timed out
    at com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseTokenVerifierImpl.fetchPublicKeys(FirebaseTokenVerifierImpl.java:283)
    at com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseTokenVerifierImpl.isSignatureValid(FirebaseTokenVerifierImpl.java:253)
    at com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseTokenVerifierImpl.checkSignature(FirebaseTokenVerifierImpl.java:158)
    at com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseTokenVerifierImpl.verifyToken(FirebaseTokenVerifierImpl.java:102)
    at com.google.firebase.auth.AbstractFirebaseAuth$3.execute(AbstractFirebaseAuth.java:307)
    at com.google.firebase.auth.AbstractFirebaseAuth$3.execute(AbstractFirebaseAuth.java:304)
    at com.google.firebase.internal.CallableOperation.call(CallableOperation.java:36)
    at com.google.firebase.auth.AbstractFirebaseAuth.verifyIdToken(AbstractFirebaseAuth.java:269)
    at com.google.firebase.auth.AbstractFirebaseAuth.verifyIdToken(AbstractFirebaseAuth.java:241)
    ...
```

In the `GooglePublicKeysManager` class, used to refresh the public keys, I noticed that the Builder is constructed like this:

```
public Builder(HttpTransport transport, JsonFactory jsonFactory) {
            this.clock = Clock.SYSTEM;
            this.publicCertsEncodedUrl = "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/certs";
            this.transport = (HttpTransport)Preconditions.checkNotNull(transport);
            this.jsonFactory = (JsonFactory)Preconditions.checkNotNull(jsonFactory);
        }
```

where the URL to refresh the public keys is constant.

I assume it is not possible, but is there a way to replace the `www.googleapis.com` with my proxed URL?

Thank you!